# Elixir/Phoenix query ERROR (grouping_error)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, psql

I have the following query:

```
fooditems = Repo.all(from p in OrderItem, join: f in Food,
                                          on: p.food_id == f.id,
                                          where: p.inserted_at >= ^date_from and p.inserted_at <= ^date_to,
                                          group_by: f.name,
                                          select: %{name: f.name, quantity: sum(p.quantity)},
                                          order_by: [desc: f.category_id])
```

`OrderItem` table has `food_id` column, while `Food` table have `name` and `category_id`. I need the result to be ordered by the `category_id` of the `Food` table. However, the query doesn't seem to work. It is returning:

```
ERROR (grouping_error): column "f1.category_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

But, I don't want to group it by category, only to present it (order_by) in a way that items from the same `category_id` are shown together. 
How can I make the query to list the items by `category_id`? Thanks

Comment: What happens when you add another `group_by` clause with the `category_id`? From what I can tell this should fix your problem? I think the error is saying you can't group by name, and order_by category_id because they will contradict each other

Comment: Thanks @HarrisonLucas, added another group_by and now it seems to work. I thought If i'll have 2 group by, it will select only the last one, but I was wrong.

Comment: @Ilya Is it possible when food with the same name is present in different categories?

Comment: Hey @JustMichael, nope, each food only linked to one particular category.

Comment: @Ilya Then Harrison's solution should work just fine :)

Comment: @JustMichael Thank you! I've posted the final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @HarrisonLucas, changed my query to the following:

```
fooditems = Repo.all(from p in OrderItem, full_join: f in Food,
                                          on: p.food_id == f.id,
                                          where: p.inserted_at >= ^date_from and p.inserted_at <= ^date_to,
                                          group_by: f.name,
                                          group_by: f.category_id,
                                          select: %{name: f.name, quantity: sum(p.quantity)},
                                          order_by: [asc: f.category_id])
```

Now it seems to work. Thanks!